# How to convert FormData to object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

[image]

I'm using react and this data is in state. How to convert such data into normal object or array?

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that everyone can understand it properly. [see why you shouldn't post image as a code or an error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Comment: have you tried `Object.fromEntries()` function?

Comment: wow! thanks for the answer, Krzysztof! You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Object.fromEntries` method

```js
// data is an object with the values inside formData
let data = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())
```

Comment: Just `Object.fromEntries(formData)` worked for me.